# How to resolve lazy initialization in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Query fails to run because of lazy initialization in pojo, how to resolve this issue? I dont have any choice to remove `@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` from Pojo.
please suggest any solution for this.

**POJO**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sof_line_item_cust_site_info")
public class SofLineItemCustomerSiteInfo {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name="sof_line_item_cust_site_id_pk")
   private int custSiteInfoId;

   @Column(name="is_active")
   private String isActive;

   @Column(name="is_cust_site")
   private String isCustomerSite;

   @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="sof_line_item_id_fk")
   private SOFServicePartInfo sofServicePartInfo;
 }
```

**DAO**

```
public boolean isCustSiteSof(List<Integer> lineItemIdList) {
        System.out.println(">>>"+lineItemIdList);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        boolean status=false;
        List<SofLineItemCustomerSiteInfo> sofLineItemCustomerSiteInfos=null;
        try {
            Query query=session.createQuery("from SofLineItemCustomerSiteInfo where sofServicePartInfo in (:sofServicePartInfos) and isCustomerSite='Y'");
            query.setParameterList("sofServicePartInfos", lineItemIdList);
            sofLineItemCustomerSiteInfos=query.list();

            if(sofLineItemCustomerSiteInfos!=null && !sofLineItemCustomerSiteInfos.isEmpty()){
                status=true;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return status;
    }
```

**Hibernate fired below query on console**

```
from sof_line_item_cust_site_info soflineite0_ where (soflineite0_.sof_line_item_id_fk in (?)) and soflineite0_.is_cust_site='Y'
```

**Exception by catch block**

```
could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.nm.model.services.vo.SOFServicePartInfo.sofServicePartId
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Lazy initialization problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930989/hibernate-lazy-initialization-problem)

Comment: @RushikeshMaliye make a join  on mapping column

Comment: @RushikeshMaliye : put `SOFServicePartInfo` class. hibernate need getter and setter for fields.

Comment: A `join fetch` will do, where the additional `fetch` does exactly that.

Comment: where to put join fetch in my code? @JoopEggen

Comment: Before `where` after the from-part. But in general other problems may arise; joining should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved with below query (thanks @Joop Eggen )**

```
from SofLineItemCustomerSiteInfo s JOIN FETCH s.sofServicePartInfo sp where sp.sofServicePartId in (:sofServicePartInfos) and s.isCustomerSite='Y'
```